# Logging data - selecting part of log file

Tags: text-processing, logs

I'm doing a small project with two Raspberry Pi's. I want to sync their clocks using Precision Time Protocol (one as master clock and another as slave clock).

Now I'm interested in logging the data you see when using the `-V` command. I'm doing the following atm:

For RPi 1:

```
sudo ptpd --interface wlan0 -M -L
```

For RPi 2:

```
sudo ptpd --interface wlan0 -s -L -V > onewaydelay.csv
```

The output is the typical

```
#Timestamp, State, Clock ID, One Way Delay, Offset From Master, Slave to Master, Master to Slave, Observed Drift, Last Packet Received.
```

The thing is I'm only interested in logging the Timestamp and One Way Delay so that I can plot the One Way Delay and see how it changes over time. So my question is:

- Is it possible to edit the output (using the -V command) so that it only prints Timestamp and One Way Delay?

Using the `-V` command the output looks (one line - comma separated):

```
2017-10-12 14:41:48.763883, slv, b827ebfffe9adfc7(unknown)/01, 0.045879356, -0.145651366, 0.319974024, -0.108966784, -500000.000000000, S
```

Comment: Using the -V command the output looks (one line - comma separated):
2017-10-12 14:41:48.763883, slv, b827ebfffe9adfc7(unknown)/01, 0.045879356, -0.145651366, 0.319974024, -0.108966784, -500000.000000000, S

Comment: 1) I put back your comment in original question to make it more readable. 2) I edit title, this is hardly a precision time problem, but rather a filtering one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to pipe to awk? e.g

```
sudo ptpd --interface wlan0 -s -L -V | awk /Timestamp,OneWayDel/ > onewaydelay.csv
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. I even tried only doing all the following variations:

... | awk /Timestamp,OneWayDel/ > onewaydelay.csv

... | awk /Timestamp,OneWayDelay/ > onewaydelay.csv

... | awk /Timestamp/ > onewaydelay.csv

... | awk '/Timestamp/' > onewaydelay.csv

... | awk /One Way Delay/ > onewaydelay.csv

... | awk '/One Way Delay/' > onewaydelay.csv


In every case the .csv file contains no data at all.

Answer (score 0):

what your are looking for is

```
| awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$4;}'
```

where

- `-F,` tell awk to separate field on comma
- `printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$4;` print 1st and 4th field separated by , (you can use ; if you like)

to have only HMS

```
| awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s\n",substr($1,10,8),$4;}'
```

using `substr(string,from,length)`'s awk function.

Comment: It works. Is it possible to exclude the date from the Timestamp so it only shows hour:minute:second?